# Does aging affect our taste in music?

Tags: genre, psychology

When I was in school I was fan of pop music as I grow up I found Rock more interesting. Later I found myself more in hiphop which end into trance,techno and electronic music in college days. Now I have job and I hear mostly classic and ambient music. It's like I been exploring music all my life and now at the age of 25 I enjoy all music genre.

My question is if music genre and age group are somehow related ? or it is just me.

Comment: Consider re-writing the question a little so that it could be answered in a factual way, rather than opinion-based  - maybe if you add at the end "...and what the data is for and against the question"

Comment: @Angst I do agree that a bit of data would make for a good answer here. However, I really think this question is fine as it stands - the concepts of age, musical genre, and 'liking something', are all objectively-defined *enough* that a general, non-personal answer can be made.

Comment: Many bands begin to slow down or start winding their music down as they age.  The first one that pops into my head is Rod Stewart, whose later output was extremely mellow while being known in his early years as a straight-out rocker and hard partier.  Even Metallica ended up playing with an orchestra on one release.  There are probably dozens upon dozens of other examples.

Me, on the other hand, grew up listening to Yes, Genesis, etc... and my favorite music has gotten steadily heavier to where I'm now attending Killswitch Engage and Slayer shows.

Answer (score 9):

A recent scientific research project actually demonstrated that yes, statistically speaking, your personal tastes align less and less with what's currently popular with each passing year.

http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2015/05/21/taste-in-music-age_n_7344322.html

According to the research it's both because we continue to like music that was popular in our youth, even as it becomes less popular, and because we begin to favor music outside the narrow range of mainstream popularity.

Comment: Is that because *our* tastes change (as per the question), or because they stay the same while fashions move on?

Comment: @topomorto edited.

Comment: Good post and interesting study in deed, but let's keep in sight that it's based on usage data from Spotify. There hasn't been Spotify for that many years yet, and the scope of popular music that the study seems to be based on is not broad enough either. The main conclusion (that we care less about fashion as wee age) makes sense to me, but I have problems for example with the assertion that "taste crystalizes around the music one is exposed to from around 16-24 years of age".

Comment: Quoting from this page https://www.aesthetics.mpg.de/en/research/department-of-music/musical-taste.html
"An individual’s musical taste can affect affiliation with...certain social groups. In this way, musical taste...establishes belonging and identity. This is especially marked among young people... Opting for different musical styles as a fan is an opportunity to try out different identities." This seems to corroborate the assertion that we care less about fashion as we age.