# Is it true that people tend to like music from their teenage years for most of their lives?

Tags: psychology

I often heard it said that people tend to end up most fond of music they listened to during their teenage years.

If true, why would this be? Have there perhaps even been scientific studies on this? Did they conclude that this is true, and if so, what are the reasons?

Comment: some overlap with topic in http://musicfans.stackexchange.com/questions/3405/does-aging-affect-our-taste-in-music/3409#3409

Comment: @Angst thanks for finding that! I was sure that there had already been something asked in this general area,

Comment: In fact I think one of the answers quotes research just on that point

Comment: @Angst yes - I may vote for this to be closed as a dupe TBH... what do you reckon?

Comment: not sure on the protocol for this kind of situation - or you could answer it yourself, referencing the other question.